# How to read file path values as columns in Spark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-synapse

I'm working in Azure Synapse Notebooks and reading reading file(s) into a Dataframe from a well-formed folder path like so:

[image]

Given there are many folders references by that wildcard, how do I capture the "State" value as a column in the resulting Dataframe?

Comment: Yes, but that contains the entire file path, not the HDFS named subsections.

Comment: try : `df = spark.read.load("abfss://....dfs.core.windows.net/")`, spark can read folders directly, and df should then contains the column `state`.

Comment: OH @Steven - I see what you did there - if I don't specify the Wildcard in the path, then I get the Path value(s) as column(s). That worked for me - if you add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use the wildcard `*`.
try : `df = spark.read.load("abfss://....dfs.core.windows.net/")`

Spark can read partitionned folders directly, and `df` should then contains the column `state` with its different values.

Comment: Marking this as the answer and just pointing out that the difference is the removal of "/State=*/.snappy.parquet" - this apparently allows Spark to automatically add the path values as columns.

Answer (score 3):

Use `input_file_name` function to get the full input path and then apply `regexp_extract` to extract the part that you want.

Example:

```py
df.withColumn("filepath", F.input_file_name())
df.withColum("filepath", F.regexp_extract("filepath", "State=(.+)\.snappy\.parquet", 1)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was really thinking (hoping?) this would be possible without parsing the filepath manually.